# Is there an open source, web-based config editor for editing valid php-style ini file?

Tags: php, cpanel, ini

Cpanel has some cool config editors that grab an .ini file, stick it all in a web form...it spits out in plain text all comments, then offers an inline text input for valid lines...so a user can change configs through the web....

I'm wondering if there's some open source software, preferably in php, that does the same...for use in a CMS.

Answer (score 1):

You could load the contents of the ini file into a textarea within a form.  Apply http://codemirror.net/ to the textarea to provide specific formatting.